# Modern Pages - Customizing layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, html, modern-pages, modern

How could I customize the layout of SharePoint Modern site?

Could I download master page for modern site and customizing this by for example a copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SharePoint Modern site does not have concept of master page. Hence you won't able to directly customize as we used to do in classic experience. You can customize modern site using below options

1. Create Application customizer to add header and footer on page.
2. You can create modern custom pages and select layout like one column, 2 column etc...

You might have to go through below resources for other available options.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages

Comment: But how wos create this Themes ? Is there posibility to change them ? http://www.topsharepoint.com/ultronic-premium-sharepoint-2013-theme

Comment: said link is for SP 2013 which does not have modern experience...also with SP online you can create custom themes but it will only allow you to choose colors etc....

Comment: Thanks for help but we must ask again. How to prepere a coode without a delay ? When we prepered header with a menu we have about two secounds delay, because the site load first, and next Extensions and webparts. How to replace one header by another without delay ?

Comment: Delay is expected as you code runs once document is ready..to handle this you should show loading image and once code does it’s part hide loading image

Answer (score 0):

You have the feature for page templates from April 2019. [Here you have the Microsoft article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/page-templates-in-sharepoint-online-faa92408-0c84-4e3d-8460-3c28065e7873) talking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Custom master pages is not supported in modern pages currently.

Quote from the article:

> Supported customizations for "modern" pages:
>
> - Custom branding
> - Adding "modern" pages programmatically
> - Adding, deleting, and updating client-side web parts on "modern" pages
> - Alternative layouts
>
> These customizations are currently not supported for "modern" pages:
>
> - Adding "classic" web parts on "modern" pages
> - Custom CSS via AlternateCSSUrl web property
> - Custom JavaScript embedded via user custom actions
> - Custom master pages (more extensive branding will be supported later using alternative options)
> - Minimal Download Strategy (MDS)  -Modern pages inside of the a Site Template package (Save site as a template)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Modern Sites requires "SharePoint Framework(spfx) Extensions" in order to extend SharePoint User Experience. It's the modern SharePoint alternative to "Master pages".

You can find official Microsoft Documentation on extensions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions).

Comment: Yes, but there is a delay two secounds in extensions.